# document.getElementsByTagName gives me an error

Tags: javascript

the error I am getting from chrome console is:

Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByTagname is not a function
at tagsName

I understand getElementsByTagName returns HTML collection (kind of an array). But I am seeing an error consistently.

Comment: Can you share the code where this error is occurring, that makes it a lot easier to debug your problem

Comment: Have you checked your case "getElementsByTagname"?

Comment: @MathKimRobin Thanks. That should be an upper case. getElementsByTagName

Comment: Please use an IDE and a linter like eslint. They would have show you where was the mistake and you would haven't lost your time for a case mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you've written

```
document.getElementsByTagname
```

Rather the 'N' in the name should be capitalized

```
document.getElementsByTagName
```

Comment: Just vote to close as a typo. The comments had already covered it.